# Split string from Redux-Form Field into multiple data points

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I'm currently working on a project that uses redux-form fields. We make use of the [react-google-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-autocomplete) component to allow users to enter an address in a similar fashion to if they were typing it in Google Maps.

Currently, we strip out the name of the location (if there is one) and just store the address. (So if I typed in "The White House", and selected the suggestion of "The White House, Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, Washington, DC", we actually end up storing "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, Washington, DC".

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import Autocomplete from 'react-google-autocomplete';

function emulateTabPress(currentEl) {
  const formEls = Array.from(currentEl.form.elements);
  const currentIdx = formEls.findIndex(el => el === currentEl);
  formEls[currentIdx + 1].focus();
}

function getFormattedGoogleAddress(googleParams) {
  return googleParams.formatted_address || googleParams.name;
}

function renderGoogleAutoComplete(props) {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      type="text"
      name="location"
      onPlaceSelected={
        param => props.input.onChange(getFormattedGoogleAddress(param))
      }
      types={[]}
      value={props.input.value}
      onChange={newValue => props.input.onChange(newValue)}
      onKeyPress={event => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
          event.preventDefault();
          emulateTabPress(event.target);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
renderGoogleAutoComplete.propTypes = {
  input: PropTypes.shape({
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onChange: PropTypes.func
  })
};

function AutocompleteLocation({ name, required }) {
  return (
    <Field
      name={name}
      required={required}
      component={renderGoogleAutoComplete}
    />
  );
}

AutocompleteLocation.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  required: PropTypes.bool
};

export default AutocompleteLocation;
```

What I WANT to do, is store three separate pieces of information

1. The address (googleParam.formatted_address)
2. The name of the location (googleParam.name)
3. The Google ID for the location (googleParam.id)

I've written code that stores this as an object and used that as the value in my  component, but then when I try to use any of the values from the store later on, it just shows as "object object"

**Any suggestions on how to get these values into discrete data elements?**